# setAccessToken() isn't working in the FB's PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
require 'facebook/facebook.php';
require 'config/fbconfig.php';
require 'config/functions.php';

include dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/session.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => ".....",
    'secret' => ".....",
));

//token variable is "false" if there no access_token
if($_POST['token'] != "false")   
     $facebook->setAccessToken($_POST['token']);
```

I am passing `access_token` using Ajax. The call to `setAccessToken()` functions seems valid as shown in the docs but it returns an undefined method error. I am sure that the token is valid as I checked it in Facebook's debugger.

**Update**: I just did `var_dump()` on the `$facebook` and it's a valid Facebook object. So the error is probably not here.

Comment: Are you using the latest/updated PHP SDK ? Downloaded from their github repo!

Comment: Please tell us the original error message.

Comment: @VirendraRajput: Followed your advice and no problems anymore. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the latest version of PHP SDK from [Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/) & replace it with the current one that you're using.